Problem when using saxon as engine to transform XML
I have a single xslt that converts the RFC list obtained from here to an internal format (also in xml).
The xslt code is pretty obvious, it includes templates that match the first two levels of the xml file.
It used to work fine, but at some point the stylesheet stopped working as expected, and now the saxon engine does not seem to match the tags anymore. For instance a expression like:
   <xsl:value-of select="count(//rfc-entry)"
returns 0. However, something like <xsl:value-of select="count(//node()[name() = 'rfc-entry'])"/> works fine!
And templates like:
   <xsl:template match="rfc-entry">
do not seem to be triggered by the input file.
I'm using saxon9-HE, and I've upgraded my JDK, but this is occurring in both OpenJDK 11 and OpenJDK 22, so I don't think it's an issue with the JDK.
Any clue that can be happening?

Please provide a short way to reproduce the problem - see [mcve].

If you want us to debug your code, you need to show us your code. But it sounds very much like the common pitfall of failing to take namespaces into account. Search this site for "XSLT default namespace" to see a few hundred examples of people falling into that trap.

This question actually got debugged in the "Staging Ground", but it looks like the question has graduated to the main part of the site without the comments. I will add an answer.

Your XML input has a default namespace declaration rfc-index xmlns="https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc-index" so any XSLT/XPath 2 or 3 supposed to take that into account needs to declare xpath-default-namespace="https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc-index", then, where that declaration is in scope, the xsl:template match="rfc-entry" will work and the count(//rfc-entry) will not give 0 but e.g. 9440. Without such a declaration match="rfc-entry" matches elements with local name rfc-entry in no namespace and the count is computed of elements in no namespace, so for your input no match/0.

Thank you also Martin for the tip. That was the root cause and everythign is now back to normal.

I had a look at the file in the Internet Archive's "Wayback Machine" and it turns out that at some point between 2020 and present day, the editors of the rfc-index decided to change the namespace URI of their document from http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc-index to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc-index (i.e. changing http: to https:). That was their mistake, but now there's no option but to change the namespace declaration in the XSLT in the same way, so that it works once again.

In recent years there's been a big trend to replace the http protocol with https everywhere, for sound reasons of improving security, so I can imagine that someone changed this namespace URI without really understanding that the URI of an XML namespace is just a unique identifier and is not used as a locator, so the schema (whether http: or https: or any other) is effectively just a string of characters, with no real connection to a network protocol. Changing it could only cause disruption.

Thank you Michael Kay and Conal Tuohy. The problem was for the namespace that was recently updated to https. Adding that tiny "s" made things back to normal. Thank you for all the feedback, I've been working in xslt for many years but I got caught in that "hidden" trap.
